# Python Developing on Mac

Tags: python, user-interface

This may seem like a dumb question but I have IDLE and I'm trying to develop a python application on my mac. I searched the internet for a GUI developer program and I heard about Tkinter but I'm not sure how to download it. Are there any good python gui developing programs? If so, where can I find them?

Comment: Are you looking for an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) which lets your write code, run it, execute it, etc.; or are you looking for a library/toolkit for developing GUI applications for Mac with Pyhon?

Comment: Try PyQt4. It has Qt Designer, a drag-and-drop GUI builder. I use it for all of my GUI projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is included with the python installed in your Mac. [Rapydtk](http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/) will help you out with doing the design.

There is also [wxWidgets](http://www.wxpython.org/), which is a pain to use right now since its not fully ready effor a 64-bit cocoa environment. I use wxWidgets, as do a lot of other projects (scite is a great example). You can use [wxglade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) with wxWidgets on Mac os which is decent.

You can also use [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and the associated qt libraries. Qt designer exists to help you out with doing the GUI.

If you are willing to go os x native only you can use the [cocoa-objective-c bridge](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/). Here you can use the interface builder component of Xcode. (might be abandoned though)

Also there is [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) which is a little bit of a different concept but you'll still be able to make a "desktop" application. I'm not sure if there is an app to help with your GUI here though.

I'm positive there are more, but those are the big ones off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to develop GUI programs with Python.

Try [this tutoral on Tkinter](http://openbookproject.net/py4fun/gui/tkPhone.html).

Comment: in this tutorial, when I do win = Tk(), nothing happens

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get a nice little window with a rocket icon when I do that. I'm running the official Python 2.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Comment: I'm running python 2.7.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2, should this make a difference?

Comment: I don't know and can't find any answer by quick googling, sorry... Just to make sure, is your Tk the Apple Tk 8.5.9?

Comment: Honestly not sure, could you tell me how to check? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tried with Python 2.7.5 that comes pre-installed on OsX 10.9.5 and it seems to work.